# Storing and Retrieving a JSON Obj from a Cookie

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, cookies

I have looked at many SO and haven't been able to figure out how to actually make this work using pure JS. My problem is that I need to add a 2 different urls to a json array and store it into a cookie for access across subdomains (i looked into the iframe local storage thing and it won't work for this application and the json array will be rather small so 4k cookie limit is plenty).

Now what I have is the following:

```
function getProject(){
  var url_str = window.location.href;
  var ProjectImgId = url_str.split('projectId=')[1];
  ProjectImgId = ProjectImgId.split('&')[0];

  var UserId = url_str.split('flashId=')[1];
  var ImageURL = 'https://project-api.artifactuprising.com/project/' + ProjectImgId + '/thumbnail?user=' + UserId;

  var RecentProjects = {"url" : url_str, "img" : ImageURL};
return RecentProjects;
}
```

The above will run on a certain page load. I want to be able to do the following with this: retrieve any existing Projects and if there isn't a match on the url, I wan to push the `RecentProjects` to the cookie array.

Here is where I am getting stumped. I am following w3 School's cookie set up which has worked for me in the past but I am unable to figure out how to push and pull this data using stringify and parse.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var recent = getCookie("yourRecentProjects");
  if (recent != "") {
// this is where I would want to parse the JSON and then check if the getProject.url value is in the current cookie json and if it is not, push it.
  } else {
    recent = getProject();
    if (recent != "" && recent != null) {
      setCookie("yourRecentProjects", recent, 365);
    }
  }
}
```

I am pretty stumped. I have figured out how to do all this using local storage, then i realized this doesn't work across subdomains so great learning experience but not a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

well, the cookie isn't json, it's just a string with a bunch of key values.

not 100% what you are looking to do with the data, but as an example, this is taken from the MDN, example #3, as for how to parse that string to find a specific value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie:

```
function doOnce() {   
   if (!document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('doSomethingOnlyOnce'))) {
   alert("Do something here!");
   document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";   
} }
```

`String.prototype.split()` creates an array of substring segments that are delimited by the value you pass in, the `Array.prototype.find()` will look at each value in the array until it either finds the substring that starts with that value, or returns `undefined` if it finds nothing.

In you case, you'd do `document.cookie.split("")` to create the array of key value substrings, which at that point you can unpack the data in many ways. maybe you are just looking for the existence of the url value, in which case `Array.prototype.includes()` is what you are looking for.